# Laravel で POST 送信しても、表示させると空になる

Tags: php, laravel

PHP を習得し、最近書籍などをもとに Laravel を学んでいる初心者です。
参考書で紹介されている Blade テンプレートも使って「名前を入力したら同じ URL のまま表示が変わり、入力された名前が表示される」というコードを書いたのですが、フォームで送信した文字が表示されません。なお、ローカル環境で確認しています。

#### 想定している動作

`http://localhost/laravelapp/hello`にアクセスすると、「お名前を入力してください。」と入力フォームが表示され、テキストボックスに名前を入力し送信ボタンをクリックすると、`http://localhost/laravelapp/hello`のアドレスのまま「こんにちは、<入力した文字列>さん！」

なお、Laravel の`public`を URL からなくすために、下記 Web ページを参考に`public`フォルダーからファイルを移動させています。

[Laravelのドキュメントルートを変更する - Laravel学習帳](https://laraweb.net/environment/347/)

ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

**参考:**
『PHPフレームワークLaravel入門 第2版』

##### 開発環境

Windows 11 (22H2)
XAMPP 8.2.4
Laravel 10.23.1

#### 現状のコード

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('hello', 'App\Http\Controllers\HelloControler@index');
Route::post('hello', 'App\Http\Controllers\HelloControler@post');
```

app/Http/Controllers/HelloControler.php

```
class HelloControler extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request) {
        $data = [
            'msg'=>'お名前を入力してください。'
        ];
        return view('hello.index', $data);
    }
    
    public function post(Request $request) {
        $msg = $request->msg;
        $data = [
            'msg'=>'こんにちは、' . $msg . 'さん！'
        ];
        return view('hello.index', $data);
    }
    
}
```

resources/views/index.blade.php

```
<p>{{$msg}}</p>
<form action="" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="msg">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$request->msg`を`$request['msg']`に変更すると、POST の値を受け取ることができました。

コントローラーのコード:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

class HelloController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $data = [
            'msg' => 'お名前を入力してください。'
        ];
        return view('index', $data);
    }
    
    public function post(Request $request) {
        $data = [
            'msg' => 'こんにちは、' . $request['msg'] . 'さん！'
        ];
        return view('index', $data);
    }
}
```

参考:
[LaravelでのPOST/GETの受け取り方法 - Laravel学習帳](https://laraweb.net/knowledge/2141/)